# Store and access large amout of data

Tags: c#, storage

I have a question regarding storing and accessing large amount of data in C#.

I programmed a data analyzer and logger, and it has to log data over days. The Data is stored in a new 2D Array every 0.1s, currently only "saved" in RAM. 
While logging, the data needs to be access-able in the GUI.
What is the best way to make this happen?
Simple binary serialization is slow and makes the on-time-GUI not running smooth.
I also tried databases like db4o, but they use a hugh mount of HDD space.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Personally, I love these things they call "databases".

Answer (score 1):

I cannot recommend enough using [TeaFiles](https://github.com/discretelogics/TeaFiles.Net) for this kind of scenario.

Basically, it is a wrapper around binary data stored in a float file on the disk.

Here is the example given on the main page to see how it works:

```
// define time series item type
struct Tick
{
    public Time Time;
    public double Price;
    public int Volume;
}
 // create file and write values
using (var tf = TeaFile<Tick>.Create("acme.tea"))
{
    tf.Write(new Tick { Price = 5, Time = DateTime.Now, Volume = 700 });
    tf.Write(new Tick { Price = 15, Time = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), Volume = 1700 });
    // ...
}
// sum the prices of all items in the file
using (var tf = TeaFile<Tick>.OpenRead("acme.tea"))
{
    return tf.Items.Sum(item => item.Price);
}
```

I use it in production to decimate and plot a range within several millions dots, and it works very well.

Comment: I know this is a solution from 2015, but it still stays true to this day (2023). I have compared the performance of loading of 2mil.270k.sth candlesticks. The results for different deserialization options: Read from SQLite file: 11287 ms. Read from JSON (properties are just 1 letter, no intents): 3842 ms, Load from Binary(Gzip compressed): 35308 ms, Load from Binary(non-compressed): 7058 ms, Load from TeaTime file (this solution): 595 ms.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to store your data in an array.
You can:

a) use the file system and write the data to a text file, or better;

b) use a database. If you don't need a standard database solution and would prefer something a little smaller and embedded, you could go with SQLite ([here's a getting started guide for C#](http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/))

If you do want something a little more robust and have access to SQL Server, then you can use that. If you want to go for a lightweight and embedded approach down a similar path as SQLite but want something a little more "*established*" I'd recommend [LocalDB](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string), [MSDN Walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If "huge" is not really huge, then maybe using postgreSQL as a database is the answer for you. postgreSQL have array data type, thus you could directly save your array as a single value. ie:
Consider this simple table having only an Id column (autoinc) and an aVals to store a 2D array of integers:

```
create table arrayLog (
 id serial,
 aVals integer [][]
)
```

From C# you could do like this:

```
using (NpgsqlConnection con=new NpgsqlConnection(@"..."))
{
  string iCmd = "insert into arrayLog (aVals) values (@aVals)";
  var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(iCmd,con);

  int[,] vals = new int[,] {
    {40,50,90},
    {400,500,900}
  };

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aVals", vals);

  con.Open();
  cmd.Parameters["@aVals"].Value = vals;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
}
```

You would do the preparation part once and just assign new array to .Value and call ExecuteNonQuery() in succession (and you would want to wrap this with a transaction for performance).

AFAIK, other SQL series databases like SQLite, SQL server do nt have this capability but I may be wrong.